# Facebook like with responsive confirm box for mobile/tablet

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, responsive-design

having a bit of difficulty with my first responsive site and the facebook like button. I have set the button to Recommend using the xfbml code and when it is clicked a confirmation / add personal message box appears as normal. Except it doesn't fit into my tablet nor mobile width. With sharer.php being withdrawn, I have to use this method for Liking, but I'm struggling to get things to work at the sizes I need.

I'm surprised Facebook hasn't looked into making Responsive=true a parameter of the Like button.

I read that this part cannot be bypassed until Facebook trusts the site, so I looked into finding the styling of the box with firebug so see if my responsive site can edit it but a whole bundle of code is loaded so I was wondering if anyone knew a list of the main styles to edit so I can apply some local responsive styling to the popup?

thanks

frank

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep in mind that the FB like button dialog loads inside an iFrame (even if you use XFBML) in order to style it.

Or, you could easily change the width property to 320px, which should be ok for most phones.